How long will it take for a Gambler to lose all their money?
In my computer programming class, we are learning about a problem called "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin". In this problem, a gambler has a fixed probability of winning and losing - and will keep playing until some stopping condition is met (e.g. runs out of money, doubles their initial bet).
I wrote the following simulations for two types of Gambler Ruin problems (Run until 0 dollars (type1) and run until 0 dollars or 10 dollars (type2)).
Here is the first one:
# Type 1
initial_funds <- 5
num_simulations <- 100


results <- numeric(num_simulations)

for (i in 1:num_simulations) {
funds <- initial_funds
turns <- 0
while (funds > 0) {
    turns <- turns + 1
    if (runif(1) < 0.5) {
        funds <- funds + 1
    } else {
        funds <- funds - 1
    }
}
results[i] <- turns
}

#print(results)
mean(results)

And here is the second one:
# Type 2
initial_funds <- 5
win_target <- 10
num_simulations <- 100


results <- numeric(num_simulations)

for (i in 1:num_simulations) {
funds <- initial_funds
turns <- 0
while (funds > 0 && funds < win_target) {
    turns <- turns + 1
    if (runif(1) < 0.5) {
        funds <- funds + 1
    } else {
        funds <- funds - 1
    }
}
results[i] <- turns
}


#print(results)
mean(results)

When I compare the results of 100 simulations, I get:
#Type 1
> mean(results)
[1] 6896.76

#Type 2
> mean(results)
[1] 22.52

Logically I can understand this. In type 1, the game can last a really long time because if the gambler happens to go on a winning streak, it might take a very long time to crawl back down towards 0 and go bankrupt. But in type 2, the game is bounded between two "barriers" : the gambler is much more likely to finish the game faster (win or lose). In type1, there is no winning condition (only losing condition). In type2, there is a winning and losing condition.
But as such, can someone please help me understand how to derive the mathematical formulas needed to describe the expected number of turns it takes for type1 to finish, and the expected number of turns it takes for type2 to finish? And the probabilities of finishing the game at any given turn? Where do these mathematical formulas come from?
Ideally, I would like to be able to create my own rules and stopping conditions for a custom gamblers ruin problem ... and then use these formulas to understand the expected number of turns until the game stops.
Note: I have taken lots of courses in math (e.g. 3 linear algebra courses, 4 calculus courses) and am comfortable reading math explanations. I also have classmates/colleagues I can consult with if someone can write the mathematical derivations here,

The theoretical expectation for the number of rounds of a fair game where you start with positive $a$ and stop at $0$ is infinite though you have probability $1$ of finishing in finite time.  The theoretical expectation for the number of rounds of a fair game where you start with positive $a$ and stop at the first of $0$ or $b>a$ is $a(b-a)$, which is $25$ here: note that $a(b-a)=1+\frac12(a-1)(b-a+1)+\frac12(a+1)(b-a-1)$.

Somewhat more generally, consider a finite Markov chain: there are $n$ possible "states", which I'll number $1$ to $n$, and an $n \times n$ matrix $P$ (the transition matrix), where the entry $P_{ij}$ is the probability,
given you are in state $i$, that the next state is $j$.  Let $u_{ik}$ be the
probability that you ever get to state $k$, given that you start in state $i$.
Then $u_{kk} = 1$, $u_{ik} = 0$ if it's impossible to ever get to $k$ starting at $i$, while $u_{ik} = \sum_{j} P_{ij} u_{jk}$ otherwise.
Let $K$ be a set of "terminal" states, and $v_i$ the expected number of steps, starting in state $i$, until you get to a state in $K$ (assuming it is certain that eventually you will get to such a state).   Thus $v_k = 0$ if $k \in K$, otherwise $v_i = 1 + \sum_{j} P_{ij} v_j$.
In both cases, a little linear algebra will get the answer.

thank you! can you please show the algebra later if you have time?
